# Регрессия. Выполнить предсказание какой-либо целевой переменной

Tags: машинное-обучение, big-data

Возможно я спрошу глупость, не судите строго, я новичок. Предположим у нас есть данные и надо выполнить предсказание какой-либо целевой переменной. Не важно какая это переменная бинарная или цифровая, а важно следующее - объект, свойство которого задаётся целевой переменной, может участвовать в обучающем наборе данных несколько раз.

Положим такой обучающий набор, где поле спортсмен является зависимым:

```
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| ФИО   | Утренняя пробежка, км | Вечерняя пробежка, км | Спортсмен |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|Иванов | 10                    |   15                  | Да        |
|Иванов | 5                     |   13                  | Да        |
|Петров | 3                     |   7                   | Нет       |
|Петров | 4                     |   2                   | Нет       |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

И набор для предсказания:

```
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| ФИО   | Утренняя пробежка, км | Вечерняя пробежка, км | Спортсмен |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
|Сидоров| 12                    |   14                  |  ?        |
|Сидоров| 11                    |   6                   |  ?        |
+-------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

В обоих наборах присутствуют записи, относящиеся к одному объекту, но разнесённые по разным строкам (положим из-за даты)
Допустим мы обучили модель, которая предсказывает как-то данные. Как в этой модели учесть то, что предсказания должны совпадать для одинаковых объектов (Сидоров не может быть и спортсменом и не спортсменом в разное время)? Возможно нужно приводить к одной строке для каждого объекта обучающий набор или быть может существует какой-то параметр, который создаёт жёсткую зависимость от столбца объекта?